# How to Access Web Activity Output Elements from Data Array in Next Activity in ADF

Tags: arrays, if-statement, azure-data-factory

I am using a Web activity and output is below after GET:

{
"status": "success",
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
"employee_salary": 320800,
"employee_age": 61,
"profile_image": ""
},
{
"id": 2,
"employee_name": "Garrett Winters",
"employee_salary": 170750,
"employee_age": 63,
"profile_image": ""
},
{
"id": 3,
"employee_name": "Ashton Cox",
"employee_salary": 86000,
"employee_age": 66,
"profile_image": ""
},
{
"id": 4,
"employee_name": "Cedric Kelly",
"employee_salary": 433060,
"employee_age": 22,
"profile_image": ""
},
{
"id": 5,
"employee_name": "Airi Satou",
"employee_salary": 162700,
"employee_age": 33,
"profile_image": ""
}......................

Now in **If Condition Activity**, *I want to write a check on "employee_age" <30 from all the elements.*

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaZTK.png)

Using expression "@less( activity('Web').output.data.employee_age,30 )" fails.

If using "@less( activity('Web').output.data[0].employee_age,30 )" it only applies the rule to first array index.

How to apply rule on all array indexes?

Expect the result to access all array indexes and apply condition check from Web activity output.

Answer (score 0):

Since the result of the web activity is an array of objects, you need to use a foreach activity to loop on all the objects, and put the if activity inside the foreach , to test each object.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here in an example they used direct;y IF after Getmetadata https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188082/manipulating-array-using-get-metadata-and-if-activ . How it worked there right after array if you could help

Comment: It's not the same. They test for a string that exists anywhere in the results. You want to test for a value larger then x on each item. I think foreach is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `filter` activity on the result of your web activity (on data array). I have taken the sample web activity response in a json file and used lookup to read it.

[image]

- Now in filter activity, use the following dynamic content for items and condition respectively to get the objects where employee age is less than 30.

```
#since I used look up, I am using the following dynamic content. You can use webactivity response to point to the data array


items : @activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].data

condition : @greater(30,item().employee_age)
```

- The result would be as shown below for the above case:

[image]